# Can "problematic" be used as a noun?

Tags: nouns

Can "problematic" be used as a noun, as a synonym for dilemma, conundrum, or a problem which gives rise to a study?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: In general (though no doubt with lots of exceptions), an adjective can be used as a noun to denote the class of things described by that adjective -- "the selfish", "the rich", "the poor", "the religious".

Comment: @Hot Licks  I agree.  I think, however, that adjectives can be used as nouns in a wider way than this.  One example is that in the world of legal matters, at least in the USA, I have heard specialists speak of 'an interrogatory', meaning a question related to a formal statement made by the other party.  Similarly, I could imagine a 'problematic'.  This was an established usage in ancient Greek and Latin.  So I do not think it is fully established.  So "I am suffering an unjust" sounds weird.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be used as a noun ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/problematic)):

> **problematic** *noun*
>
> something that is problematic: a problematic aspect or concern

Comment: Well, that's certainly legitimate. No argument. But that said, I'd be inclined simply to use _problem_.

Comment: I'd be inclined simply to use _problem_ too, but in academic writing, I believe, **problematics** is a more appropriate word to use. [COCA shows 82 cases](https://imgur.com/zuHy822), for example (in the image it is possible to see only 23), most of which are clearly used in, as I said, academic context. It is somewhat strange to say _"problems of contemporary art"_ (well, it is not _strange_, it just means the other thing) as it is questionable to say that contemporary art has any problems ([example paper](https://www.gla.ac.uk/media/Media_461960_smxx.pdf)).

Comment: It depends on the context. **Problematic** (n. countable) is usually used in the plural and is not identical to "problem". A problematic is the source of the problem, and not the problem itself. Thus 3x + 4x = 24; 4x + 3y = 22 is the **problem**. The problematics are that nobody who is present understands algebra, and the maths teacher is on holiday.

Comment: I ran out of characters while writing the first comment, but I want to clarify what I meant. If we say "**Problematics** of Contemporary Art", the entire meaning changes. We are now talking about.. well, what is contemporary art **about**, what the authors are trying to tell us. Same goes for literature: "Problems of Robert Frost's poetry"... well, it doesn't seem that poetry of Robert Frost has any problems. Again, if we instead say "**Problematics** of Robert Frost's poetry", we are exploring what Robert Frost was trying to tell in his poems.

Comment: @Greybeard didn't you mean 3x + 4**y** = 24; 4x + 3y = 22 ? Task makes sense anyway though.

Comment: Interesting and really good distinctions. There's also the word _issue_.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots without proper alt text. They do not get indexed by internal or external search engines properly, they do not resize consistently on different devices, and they are useless for people using text browsers or screen readers. I have replaced your screenshot with the text it represents.

Comment: Oh... I sincerely apologise. Screenshots truly have all these disadvantages, I will keep this in mind while writing answers to different questions. Thank you for pointing out the mistake and for taking your time to edit my answer!